# Python urlparser Gives wrong result

Tags: python, parsing, url, urlparse

I'm trying to separate the different parts of a url with python
s urlparse, but I'm seeming to get the wrong values in the results.

```
baseline = runSql(conn,"Select url from malware_traffic where tag = 'baseline';")

for i in baseline:
    print i[0]
    print urlparse.urlparse(i[0])
```

the runSql function just returns a list of urls.  I loop through them and attempt to turn the urls from the baseline variable into urls, but the way python parses the urls seems to be incorrect

```
172.217.9.174:443/c2dm/register3
ParseResult(scheme='172.217.9.174', netloc='', path='443/c2dm/register3', params='', query='', fragment='')
connectivitycheck.gstatic.com:80/generate_204
ParseResult(scheme='connectivitycheck.gstatic.com', netloc='', path='80/generate_204', params='', query='', fragment='')
www.google.com:80/gen_204
ParseResult(scheme='www.google.com', netloc='', path='80/gen_204', params='', query='', fragment='')
172.217.9.174:443/auth/devicekey
ParseResult(scheme='172.217.9.174', netloc='', path='443/auth/devicekey', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

In the results you can clearly see that it is mixing up scheme and netloc as well as including the port in path.

For instance the first result should be this.

```
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='172.217.9.174:443', path='/c2dm/register3', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

not sure why it's getting messed up.

I'm practically using the same thing as one of the examples in the documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html.

So what am I doing wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: None of your URLs start with `http://` or even `//`, which the documentation _specifically_ mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your urls don't have a scheme (the `http://` part), so python thinks `172.217.9.174:` is the scheme. Prefixed with `http://` everything works as expected:

```
>>> urlparse('172.217.9.174:443/c2dm/register3')
ParseResult(scheme='172.217.9.174', netloc='', path='443/c2dm/register3', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://172.217.9.174:443/c2dm/register3')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='172.217.9.174:443', path='/c2dm/register3', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: right, I know why it's doing it, I would just think it would be smart enough to recognize that.  The docs here suggest it is not needed https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: if this is the only suggestion, my workaround is to add `"//" + i[0]` inside the url parse, but I really don't like that.

Comment: `mailto:` urls don't have slashes in them, so it would be hard to make parser correctly identify such cases.